How do I sort a list of Game Objects by a date that is stored in their script?
I have a list of prefab game objects that are added to the list when they are instantiated. Each of these game objects has a script where one of the fields is a DateTime, meant to keep track of when an even happened. So one object might store the date "7/13/24" and another might store the date "6/2/2023". This is part of the script on each prefab:
public class RollHolderController : MonoBehaviour    
    public string rollDate;
    public DateTime rollDateTime;

I want to sort this list in descending order. I'm trying to use list.sort, but I can't quite seem to figure out how to get the sorting method to look at the stored date in each object.
This is what I've been using, but it's clearly not working. Can I get some help in getting this sussed out?
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class RollingHistoryController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> rollButtonList = new List<GameObject>();
    public int lookBack;

    public void SortRollsByDate()
    {
        foreach(GameObject obj in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("RollButtonObject"))
        {
                rollButtonList.Add(obj);
        }

        rollButtonList.Sort(gameObject.GetComponent<RollHolderController>().rollDateTime);
    }
}


you can add this after the foreach loop:  rollButtonList = rollButtonList.OrderByDescending(obj => obj.GetComponent<RollHolderController>().rollDateTime).ToList();

List.Sort expects an Comparison<T> parameter as you can see in the docs, this requires you to implement your own comparing method in a separate class. The easier way to sort is a List is using OrderBy or OrderByDescending which requires a lambda expression the returns the property to sort on. In your case you can use
rollButtonList.OrderByDescending(g => g.GetComponent<RollHolderController>().rollDateTime);

This returns a new sorted IEnumerable which then can be converted back to a List like this:
rollButtonList = rollButtonList.OrderByDescending(g => g.GetComponent<RollHolderController>().rollDateTime).ToList();


You can use the Sort method of the list by passing in a comparison function.  The comparison function takes in 2 items of the list, and then compare the first element to the second (below using CompareTo via IComparable).
You can make your own comparison determination by returning -1, 0, or 1 for each pair.
rollButtonList.Sort((x,y) =>
    x.GetComponent<RollHolderController>().rollDateTime.CompareTo(
    y.GetComponent<RollHolderController>().rollDateTime)
);

If you need the results sorted in the opposite direction, swap the x and y arguments in the comparison.
eg. y.CompareTo(x) rather than x.CompareTo(y)
This will sort the items of the list directly.
One issue pointed out by ipodtouch0218 is that this will run GetComponent for each comparison, which is quite heavy.  I would suggest changing the code to not require GetComponent at all by finding the objects by the type instead of by tag.
private List<RollHolderController> rollButtonList = new List<RollHolderController>();

foreach (var rollButton in FindObjectsOfType<RollHolderController>())
{
    rollButtonList.Add(rollButton);
}

rollButtonList.Sort((x,y) =>
    x.rollDateTime.CompareTo(y.rollDateTime)
);


This would most likely perform worse than Efraim Newman's answer, since GetComponent would run every comparison, instead of only once for every element. Fine for smaller lists, but would scale worse at bigger lists.

@ipodtouch0218 That is true, but for the sake of knowing you can pass in a comparison directly was the purpose (the other answer specifically states you cannot do what i posted without creating another class, which is incorrect).  rollButtonList should really be a List, no GetComponent should be required at all.
